# How to rearrange code using Regular Expressions in HaxeDevelop / FlashDevelop Find and Replace

Tags: regex, haxe, flashdevelop

I'm trying to turn **cast(("Sparkles"), GetBitmapData);**  to **GetBitmapData("Sparkles");**

I've got this for my find code:

```
cast\(\(\"\.*\"\),\ .*\);
```

but this replace doesn't work:

```
$2\(\"$1\"\);
```

What do I need to do to make this work?

Comment: What exactly is the pattern ? Just rearranging those words ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You regex does not contain capturing groups and you try to access them with numbered backreferences. Besides, you escaped  the dot, and `\.*` just matches 0+ dot symbols.

You may use the following regex replacement:

*Find what*:       `cast\(\("(.*?)"\),\s*(\w+)\);`
*Replace with*: `$2("$1");`

Here is a [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=cast%5c%28%5c%28%22%28.*%3f%29%22%5c%29%2c%5cs*%28%5cw%2b%29%5c%29%3b&i=cast%28%28%22Sparkles%22%29%2c+GetBitmapData%29%3b%0d%0aGetBitmapData%28%22Sparkles%22%29%3b&r=%242%28%22%241%22%29%3b) (FlashDevelop S&R feature uses .NET regex flavor).

**Pattern details**:

- `cast\(\("`  - a `cast(("` substring
- `(.*?)`  - Group 1 (referred to with `$1`) capturing any 0+ chars as few as possible up to the first...
- `"\),` - a `"),` substring
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(\w+)` - Group 2 (referred to with `$2`) capturing 1+ word chars (letters/digits/`_`)
- `\);` - a `);` substring.

Comment: I forgot to circle back with the final expression that I ran with: 
cast\(\((.*?)\),\s*(\w+)\);
$2($1);

Thank you so much for this, it saved me several hours of work!

Comment: @JohnDoughty Great that you could go a step further and customize the pattern.